# Почему в отладчике VS числа отображаются примерно как 0х0000000а

Tags: visual-studio, отладчик

Подскажите пожалуйста почему в отладчике VS числа отображаются как 0х0000000а и как это исправить?

[image: скриншот visual studio с демонстрацией описанного подведения]

Comment: Обычное шестнадцатеричное число, почему бы и нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может посмотреть сюда, возможно решение тут

[image: скриншот панели инструментов visual studio с обведенной кнопкой hex]